# ZendFramework Send variables from Controller to View (Best pactice)

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, zend-view, zend-controller

I have been working in Zend Framework for a while and I am currently refactoring some parts of my code. One of the big thing I would like to eliminate is my `abstract` controller class which initiate a lot of variables which must be present in all my controller such as `$success`, `$warning` and `$error`. This part can be done in controller pluggins but what would be the best way to send these variables to the related view. Currently I am using a custom method in my `abstract` controller class which i call from within all my controllers.

```
protected function sendViewData(){
    $this->view->success  = $this->success;
    $this->view->warning  = $this->warning;
    $this->view->error    = $this->error;
}
```

which is then called in all the actions of all of my controllers throught

```
parent::sendViewData();
```

I was looking to automate this process through a plugin controller or anything better suited for this

Comment: Could you clarify please? You want help making a plugin controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a [postDisplatch](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html) method in your abstract controller to initialize the view data (See section "Pre- and Post-Dispatch Hooks").

That way, in each actions, you could initialize your `$this->success`, `$this->warnning` or `$this->error` variables, and it would be pass to the view after the action is executed.

Comment: but keep in mind that you have to call parent::postDispatch() in your concrete controller if you override the postDispatch method!

Comment: So far i wasn't aware of the postDispatch method so i don't have a problem with that, yet, but thanks for pointing out :D

Answer (score 2):

The **Best pactice** is, define a base controller and let other controllers to extend this, instead of directly calling the `Zend_Controller_Action` method

```
// Your base controller file ApplicationController.php
class ApplicationController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
       // method & variable here are available in all controllers
        public function preDispatch() {
            $this->view->success  = $this->success;
            $this->view->warning  = $this->warning;
            $this->view->error    = $this->error;
        }
}
```

Your other normal controllers would be like this

```
// IndexController.php
class IndexController extends ApplicationController {

}
```

Now these (*success, warning & error*) variable are available in all views/layout files, In `ApplicationController.php` you can also hold **shared functionality** of other controllers.