# How to run same lines in all controllers init() function?

Tags: zend-framework, controller, init, zend-framework-mvc

I need same 2 lines in all my controllers, each controller have its own init logic, but these two lines are common for all of them.

```
public function init()
{
    $fm =$this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
    $this->view->messages = $fm->getMessages();
}
```

How can I avoid repeat code ?

**Update:**

Ok, the FlashMessenger was only an example, let's say I need write a log line in every action except for 'someAction' @ 'someController'. So the new common lines should be.

```
$this->logger = new Zend_Log();
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../logs/log.txt');
$this->logger->addWriter($writer);
$this->logger->log('Some Message',Zend_Log::DEBUG);
```

The question is, where should I place these lines in order to avoid repeat them in all init() of each controller.
These lines should be placed at bootstrap?. If so: How can skip log lines for 'someAction'.
Or should I implement a 'BaseController' and make all my controller extend from it. If so: How can I Autoload it? (Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just subclass the controller:

```
class Application_ControllerAction extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function init()
    {
        $fm =$this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
        $this->view->messages = $fm->getMessages();
    }
}


class IndexController extends Application_ControllerAction {
}
```

You may also achieve the same writing Controller Plugin.

#### Edit:

[Front controller plugins](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372) are executed on each request, just like the `Controllers` and have the same hook methods:

```
routeStartup(): prior to routing the request
routeShutdown(): after routing the request
dispatchLoopStartup(): prior to entering the dispatch loop
preDispatch(): prior to dispatching an individual action
postDispatch(): after dispatching an individual action
dispatchLoopShutdown(): after completing the dispatch loop
```

I addition, you may check controller params to execute the code only on selected requests:

```
if ('admin' == $this->getRequest()->getModuleName() 
&& 'update' == $this->getRequest()->getActionName() ) …
```

Comment: Please, explain how would help the Controller Plugin

Comment: I recommend using a view helper instead of subclassing the controller, since view helpers are created exactly for this purpose. Subclassing the Controller class is a usual approach within other frameworks, but Zend  provides the helper functionality. The same goes for action helpers, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your flash messages through (you dont need to send anything from your controller to your view, it's all automated)

```
$fm = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger();
Zend_Debug::dump($fm->getMessages());
```

in you view, i would also recommand that you encapsulate this code in a view helper like it is shown on this site http://grummfy.be/blog/191

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for your answer, but I still want to know how to avoid repeat code in all your controllers.

Comment: I've asked a smilar question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347965/zendframework-send-variables-from-controller-to-view-best-pactice

Comment: @Jeff: Also, I prefer don't write _new_ in my views.

Comment: @texai : I can understand you coding preferences and I am fine with them, but if you refer to the theorical MVC design pattern, Controllers and Views can call Models, so, beside coding preference, there is nothing wrong there (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller)

Comment: @Jeff: Sometimes I call static methods of my model classes from views, but I prefer do _new_ in contrllers.

Comment: @Jeff FlashMessenger was only an example. I've set a new example, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initMyActionHelpers() {
    $fm = new My_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger();
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($fm);;
}
```

Comment: FlashMessenger thing was only an example. Please see the question update.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I avoid repeat code ?

Write your own custom controller, implement that in `init` method of that controller, and then extend all controllers in your app from your custom controller.

But approach with separate view helper as @Jeff mentioned (look at link) is often taken as a better solution.
In your controller do only:

```
$this->_helper->flashMessanger('My message');
```

and view helper will do the rest.

Comment: That's defeating the whole point of action helpers! from the docs: "Action Helpers aim to minimize the necessity to extend the abstract Action Controller in order to inject common Action Controller functionality" http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Comment: I didn't say that it good solution. More - I wrote, that view helper will be better and suggested code without need to use `init`! But question was: "how to run **something** in all controllers **init** function" - and what I wrote is pure answer for that question. So I think, that downvoting me is inequitably.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the reason for creating new custom controller. Just add this line to all you init() methods.

```
$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();
```

Comment: That is just what I want to avoid